# Persistent tail combined with concealment from Ghostwalker

Tags: dnd-4e, monk

I am not sure if I understand the level 10 Utility Power **Persistent Tail** correctly.
Let's say I have a level 11 CB-Monk Ghostwalker.

When I hit a target and slide it adjacent I get CA. I then have also concealment against that enemy. In the next round, the enemy shifts two squares. As soon as it has moved one square, I can move up to my speed immediately? Do I provoke an opportunity attack in this case?

Because my concealment lasts until the end of my next turn, I will still have concealment after my movement. If I then beat the enemy's passive (or active?) perception check, it can't see me any more.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right of it here.

You will provoke opportunity attacks if the square you are leaving is still threatened by the creature or by another creature. However, when you complete your movement you'll be able to make a stealth check as you have cover/concealment.

Your stealth check is against the enemy's passive perception, and yes, you will be hidden so he cannot see you anymore (and doesn't know where you are).

Note that this uses your immediate reaction so it is limited to 1/round.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I wait with my movement until the enemy has moved all/some of its squares to reduce the chance of provoking OA? Or do I have to move right after the enemy moved its first square?

Comment: Yes. Your movement happens after the target finishes moving (It's a reaction)